# Unable to determine SOCKS version from socks

Tags: proxy, python-requests, socks

Using proxy connection (HTTP Proxy : 10.3.100.207, Port 8080).
Using python's request module's get function, getting following error:

"Unable to determine SOCKS version from socks://10.3.100.207:8080/"

Comment: Can you please provide a code sample for your question. Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try `export all_proxy="socks5://10.3.100.207:8080"` if you want to use socks proxy.

Else `export all_proxy=""` for no proxy.
Hope This works. :D

Comment: where do we write this configuration?

Comment: Add the line `export all_proxy="<scheme://IP:port>"` in ~/.bashrc if you want this configuration permanently for the user in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this problem by removing "socks:" in_all_proxy.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

unset all_proxy && unset ALL_PROXY