# requests with proxy not working but works in curl

Tags: python, python-requests

```
import requests
response = requests.get('http://www.httpbin.org/headers')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 75, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 60, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 412, in send
    conn = self.get_connection(request.url, proxies)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 309, in get_connection
    proxy_manager = self.proxy_manager_for(proxy)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 182, in proxy_manager_for
    manager = self.proxy_manager[proxy] = SOCKSProxyManager(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/contrib/socks.py", line 192, in __init__
    raise ValueError("Unable to determine SOCKS version from %s" % proxy_url)
ValueError: Unable to determine SOCKS version from socks://IP:PORT/
```

Hell I ran the above two lines it is giving me error while connecting to proxy, so I tried curl

```
curl -v http://www.httpbin.org/headers
```

and it works fine, I tried `pip install pysocks` but it I still get the same error

note:I removed the proxy ip:port from error

I tried the solution on [Unable to determine SOCKS version from socks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39906836/unable-to-determine-socks-version-from-socks) but it gave same error

Comment: @RomanKonoval nope same issue

Comment: @RomanKonoval so if I follow up with `export all_proxy=""` it works fine, however when I export the proxy it throws the error

Comment: @RomanKonoval Yes I restarted the terminal twice, I also restarted the vps

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215483/discussion-between-goku-and-roman-konoval).